# mysql how to write the changes to memory first , then to disk

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

is there a way to commit your transactions to memory first ? and then persist the same changes on the hard disk after some time , when the work load is not heavy? im talking about like 3-5 seconds maximum. I cannot risk holding all the database on memory , i just want to reflect the changes to memory first , so that i can have a quick response , with no delay caused by the harddisk. is there a way to do this without placing all the database on memory ?

im using hibernate 3.6, mysql 5.1.22 and mysql connector 5.1.18. But i can change to mysql 5.5 if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what databases do anyway: hold the write until necessary to write to disk. You shouldn't be concerned about that, the dabatase is already doing this for you.

You can use the [Memory Storage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) in MYSQL, if you want only memory for storage and improve performance but note that the data is lost when the server is shutdown.

Comment: how can i get rid of the time spent on session.flush on hibernate then ? so i assume the time spent on session.flush is just about generating the sql statements and writing to database transaction ?

Comment: @kommradHomer I am not familiar with NHibernate but I imagine session.flush it's triggering some intensive operations, either CPU-bound or IO-Bound and may very well be forcing the database to write some stuff to disk; whatever the case is, my feeling is that the issue should be tackled on the coding side, not the database side.

Comment: im using hibernate. You are just right ; i spend the time just for creating the SQL statements , with %100 cpu , not about hard disk or DB operations.